# What's the maximum number of data points allowed to train a classifier in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, classification, machine-learning

What is the maximum number of data points allowed to train a classifier in Google Earth Engine (n columns * n rows)? I know there is some threshold that if you go above, you get a `Computed value too large"` error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limit is 100MB, so the number of rows and columns will vary depending on the data types and how the column values are generated/collected.